# ZF2 maintenance page

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I try to set up a maintenance page with ZF2 but it's not working. I put a maintenance.html page in public folder (www) and in my onbootstrap function I've got the following code :

```
    $config = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('Appli\Config'); 
    if($config['maintenance']) {
        $response  = $e->getResponse();
        $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Location', '/maintenance.html');
        $response->setStatusCode(503);
        return $response;
    }
```

I enter the if cause $config['maintenance'] is true but it's not displaying my maintenance.html page as expected. Instead it displays the page asked.
Is there something wrong about my redirection ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You appear to be attempting to short-circuit the request directly from your `onBootstrap` method. That won't work, at that point the route hasn't been resolved and the controller hasn't been dispatched. Essentially, all you're doing is pre-populating the response, only for it to be over-written once the request is routed and dispatched.

If you want to affect the response, you'll need to listen to one of the other `MvcEvent`s. It seems you want to do this before a controller is dispatched, so the place to do it would be in the `EVENT_ROUTE`, ideally with a high priority so it happens before the route is resolved by the router (saves wasted processing resolving a route that will never be dispatched).

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $events = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $events->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, function (MvcEvent $r) {
        $config = $r->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('Appli\Config');
        if ($config['maintenance']) {
            $response = $r->getResponse();
            // set content & status
            $response->setStatusCode(503);
            $response->setContent('<h1>Service Unavailable</h1>');
            // short-circuit request...
            return $response;
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Indeed I used to short-circuit the request in onBootstrap for my ACL rights and somehow wanted to do the same for maintenance page.
Your solution works fine and I like the way you cut useless process. Thanks a lot for your help and explanation

Answer (score 1):

You can't set a 503 status code *and* redirect - the two are mutually exclusive, as redirects use a 3xx status code.

You probably want something more like:

```
$response->setContent(file_get_contents('/path/to/maintenance.html'));
$response->setStatusCode(503);
```

Comment: Well that's odd, because ZF2 uses this for 404 errors and it works fine.Tried the setContent, even without the file_get_contents (put the html code directly as setContent param), and it remains unchanged. The page asked is still displayed, and content isn't changed :/