# How do I implement a maintenance mode / routing constraint?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, url-routing

I want to implement a maintenance mode. I'm thinking of a check on all methods of all my controllers, each of which extend the `AbstractActionController` class.

The goal is to simply check a boolean flag to see if maintenance mode is on and if so display a HTML page featuring a maintenance message (eg. We're currently performing maintenance. Please check back again in a few minutes)

**Instead of manually performing the check in each function**, how can I set up the check to be performed before any routing takes place?

Comment: Hey there. I separated your text in smaller paragraphs and tried to clarify the way your question is presented. Try and keep the noise to a minimum. You may want to add some details as what your actual routing is.

Comment: This answer might help -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23435610/zf2-maintenance-page/23442585#23442585

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully implemented this solution using the MVC 'dispatch' event in the `BaseController` class (which extends the `AbstractResultfulController` class, and which also is the base class for most of my action controllers).

```
public function setEventManager(EventManagerInterface $events) {
    parent::setEventManager($events);
    $events->attach('dispatch', array($this, 'checkMaintenance'), 10);
    return $this;
}

public function checkMaintenance() {
    $response = $this->getResponse();

    $message = $this->getMaintenanceModeMessageOrFalse();
    if (false !== $message) {
        $response->setStatusCode(503);
        $response->setContent($message);
        return $response;
    }
}

public function getMaintenanceModeMessageOrFalse() {
    return "We're currently performing maintenance. Please check back again in a few minutes.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think best approach to create a static maintenance page is handling this requirement in http server level, just before the actual request of the client passed to the application.

This means, you can show a maintenance page without bootstrapping your app. Also this approach will be much more faster than any application-level solution.

For [nginx](http://nginx.org/) you can try something like this:

```
location / {
  if (-f $document_root/maintenance.html) {
    return 503;
    }
  # ... your current configuration goes here ...
}

error_page 503 @maintenance;

location @maintenance {
  # This will be catch any type of request
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /maintenance.html break;
}
```

For apache:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/maintenance.html -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/maintenance.html
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !=503
RewriteRule ^.*$    /maintenance.html [L,R=503]
```

By this way, putting a `maintenance.html` file in your site root will be enough to switch entire site to maintenance mode for visitors.

When you complete the maintenance, you can delete that file. (Renaming will be reasonable to use again later).

Hope it helps.